# Bitopological spaces and algebraic topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology, homology, homotopy-theory

Is it possible to introduce the concept of bitopological spaces such as $(X,T_1,T_2)$ (introduced by J.C.Kelly see Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 13 (1963) 71–89 MR0143169, J.C. Kelly) in the homotopy theory or homology theory?

Answer (score 4):

In some sense, the (relatively new) field of [directed algebraic topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_algebraic_topology) represents an attempt to do this. [This article](http://www.dima.unige.it/~grandis/Dht1.pdf) by Marco Grandis includes a discussion (on page 8) of why bitopological spaces are too general to admit a good (directed) homotopy theory.